# Create a Maven 2 project with Struts 1 archetype

Tags: maven-2, struts-1, maven-archetype

I would like to create a web project using Maven 2 + Struts 1. Would someone provide me some tutorial or a website outlining the steps? Thank you.
;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [Struts 1 Blank Archetype](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/faqs/apps.html) for Maven 2:

```
$ mvn archetype:create                                \
      -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.struts            \
      -DarchetypeArtifactId=struts-archetype-blank    \
      -DarchetypeVersion=1.3.5                        \
      -DgroupId=com.example                           \
      -DpackageName=com.example.projectname           \
      -DartifactId=my-webapp
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you need additional information on obtaining the struts-archetype-blank archetype:

**Step #1**

The struts-archetype-blank archetype is no longer in the default Maven2 repository. Therefore you have to check it out manually from http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/struts/maven/trunk/struts-archetype-blank.

**Step #2**

Build the struts-archetype-blank-1.3.5-SNAPSHOT.jar file: `mvn install`.

**Step #3**

Install the archetype:

```
mvn install:install-file
    -DgroupId=org.apache.struts
    -DartifactId=struts-archetype-blank
    -Dversion=1.3.5-SNAPSHOT
    -Dpackaging=jar
    -Dfile=struts-archetype-blank-1.3.5-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

**Step #4**

Create your Struts1 Maven2 project (as Pascal Thivent pointed):

```
mvn archetype:create
    -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.struts
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=struts-archetype-blank
    -DarchetypeVersion=1.3.5-SNAPSHOT
    -DgroupId=com.example
    -DpackageName=com.example.projectname
    -DartifactId=my-webapp
```

**Good Luck!**

Answer (score 0):

Are you searching for a tutorial on Maven 2 or on Struts ? mvn archetype:generate should be your friend. Take a look into the [docs](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/usage.html) about archetype.

Comment: searching for a tutorial on Maven 2 using archetype struts